# If a remove the file AndroidManifest.xml, there is a way recover the file?

Tags: android

I start to practice with Android Studio, and due to my unknolegment, I remove the root file AndroidManifest.xml, so the app which I programed, get the error that the not found the AndroidManifest.xml.

My question is if there is some way to recover the file, or waht I should do to rewrite the file.

Comment: Right click on your app folder  -> Local History -> Show History -> Revert

Comment: If you use git or svn, do as Vince says, it should revert the file. If not, write your manifest file. There are plenty of examples, and you should have sufficient knowledge of manifest files anyway. If you don't, it's time to learn.